# to get last 30 records coredata NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

i want to get the last 30 records from the coredata,i want to use NSPredicate :at present

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((from == %@) AND (to == %@) )OR((from == %@) AND (to == %@))",from, to,to ,from];
[request setPredicate:predicate];


NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedContext
                                        executeFetchRequest:request
                                        error:&error] mutableCopy];
```

how to add the methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [sort descriptors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001170-BAJHFCAC) to bring it into the right order and set the [fetch limit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001170-BAJBEABG) to 30

```
NSSortDescriptor* fromSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                            initWithKey:@"from" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[fromSortDescriptor]];
[request setFetchLimit:30];
```

Comment: ithink fetchOffset is my need https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/fetchOffset